# I got 403 Error on SonarQube integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

[Jenkins build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmLpG.png)For one applications, builds are failing with a Sonar 403 error.

However, I could see the analysis reports being published.

I read on the internet that assigning browse permission would solve the problem.

However even after assigning the Projects Browse permissions, they still have a 403 error.

Also, when I change the project from Public to Private and manually run the builds, they are building successfully. My jenkins job is pipeline as code.

Sonarqube scanner MSBUild version: 4.0.2
Sonarqube server : 6.7
Jenkins : 2.107.2

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: I think you should add more details to your question. It is hard to understand what is going on when we don't see the configurations and other internal details.

Comment: passed user authentiation token for sonar log in in jenkins pipeline that token has all permissions to excute the project ..My analysis is also successfull but still got 403 error.